# How to get ORA error code in C# exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle

My code looks like this:

```
    public bool myQuery(string cmd)
    {
        try
        {
            OracleCommand command = null;
            command = new OracleCommand(cmd, sqlConnection);
            command.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;            
    }
```

My issue is when error `ORA-02291` occurs in Oracle, its Exception is not caught. No error is shown, how do I catch this error ?

Comment: Are you using the OracleClient of ADO.Net or ODP.Net?

Comment: you mean the messagebox contained no text, or the messagebox was never displayed?

Comment: messagebox was never displayed. I'm using webgui and devart. I got it now.. It was webgui issue. Sorry about that..

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
if (ex.InnerException != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, "error!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException ex)
{
    int code = ex.Code;

   // or

   string eCode = ex.ErrroCode;

    return false;
}
return true;
```